# Converting text to image with GD library not working

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and was following a lil dated tutorial on youtube

where it converts a text to an image

but after following the code.. unfortunately, all I get is a small black box on a grey background

here is my code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$email ="example@example.com";
$email_length =strlen($email);

$font_size =4;

$image_height = ImageFontHeight($font_size);
$image_width = ImageFontWidth($font_size) * $email_length;

$image = imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);

imagestring($image,$font_size,0,0,$email,$font_color);
imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

do note I am not trying to watermark an image with gd library here, but convert a text to an image

any help will be highly appreciated..thanks

Comment: This code works fine for me

Comment: i am using wamp server ..did you use wamp server ? if not what am i missing?

Comment: I tested it on several platforms and got a 152x16 px graphic with black text on a white background.
I have no idea why you got a small black box on a grey background.

Comment: What does phpinfo() deliver to the PHP version and GD ?

Comment: GD settings https://imgur.com/PFlDTwj  and what i see on my wamp server https://imgur.com/SFDuQdd

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.18

Comment: Check these points
1. is <?php in the first Line and is < the first char in your file
2. remove the ?> on the end
3. is your php file saved as UTF-8 without BOM

If your code after that not work you must debugging. 
Then contact me again, I can give hints.

Comment: oh it worked i removed spaces from  3 to 1 <? php ..thanks a lot